# Regex to capture a string between first and second whitespace

Tags: python, regex

I want to capture a string between the first and the second whitespace in all lines in my file (NP_xxxxx.1). However, the string may change, so I cannot use add "NP" and ".1" in my regex.

> HK407_02g03400    NP_585950.1 74.539  271 68  1   14  284 1   270 4.68e-143   401
> HK407_02g03530  NP_585964.1 86.989  269 35  0   1   269 1   269 0.0 495
> HK407_02g03640  NP_585974.1 70.940  117 34  0   5   121 4   120 1.19e-57    171

This is how far I've come:

`\s\S.*?\s`

https://regex101.com/r/DrFh4t/1

Comment: Why don't you read in the file line by line and use `line.split(" ")[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for extracting only part of the matched substring:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_text = '''HK407_02g03400 NP_585950.1 74.539 271 68 1 14 284 1 270 4.68e-143 401
... HK407_02g03530 NP_585964.1 86.989 269 35 0 1 269 1 269 0.0 495
... HK407_02g03640 NP_585974.1 70.940 117 34 0 5 121 4 120 1.19e-57 171'''
>>> re.findall(r"^\S*\s(\S*)", my_text, flags=re.M)
['NP_585950.1', 'NP_585964.1', 'NP_585974.1']
```